# Mutiple lines display in label using textvariable

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am using tkinter and created a label with textvariable. What I want is to have let say top 5 customer listed in this one label. The customer list is from an excel file.

Part of my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

df = pd.read_excel('Sample.xlsx', "Sheet1")

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid()

        self.baseDown = tk.Frame(root, width=800, height = 400, background='#E6E6FA', relief = "groove", borderwidth = 2)
        self.baseDown.grid(columnspan=7, row=1, rowspan = 4, pady = 1, padx = 2, sticky="wn")
        self.BDown = tk.LabelFrame(self.baseDown, text = " Analysis ", width=800, height=400, background ='#E6E6FA', relief = 'ridge', borderwidth = 2)
        self.BDown.config(font = ('Verdana', 8, 'bold'))
        self.BDown.grid(columnspan=7, row=1, rowspan = 4, pady = 3, padx = 2, sticky="wn")
        self.baseDown.grid()

        self.cust_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.lbl_custname = ttk.Label(self.BDown, textvariable = self.cust_var)
        self.lbl_custname.config(font=('Segoe UI', 8), width = 100)
        self.lbl_custname.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=3, pady = 1, padx = 2, sticky="nw")

        top = df.nlargest(5, columns=['Value'])
        for index, row in top.iterrows():
            self.cust_var.set(row[top['Customer Name'].values.astype(str)])


root = tk.Tk()
root.configure(background = 'white')
#root.resizable(False, False)
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

The output is as below:
Customer1     NaN
Customer2     NaN
Customer3     NaN
Customer4     NaN
Customer5     NaN
Name: 20371, dType: Object

Customer list is correct, but I don't understand why NaN is there and why is the datatype appearing as well.

My excel file only carry 2 columns:
Customer Name
Value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the `self.cust_var` to the result of `row[top['CustomerName'].values.astype(str)]` 5 times.

If you want to show what you expect, you simply set the variable once (replace the for loop):

```
self.cust_var.set('\n'.join(top['Customer Name'].values))
```